# Get database from XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

Hello I am going to uninstall the localhost because its not working, so I want to get the database from the xampp folder before the it's deleted. Can anybody please tell me the path..

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just export the database via PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: You should export using phpmyAdmin, just copying `xampp\mysql\data` wont work. Not sure why, something like the data is binary encoded using a random key set at install time.

Comment: phpmyadmin is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in

> xampp\mysql\data

folder. Or you can export the database in PHPmyadmin.

Comment: Only copying files from xampp\mysql\data is not enough for some unknown reason. It is making problems for me at least.

Answer (score 3):

You can copy the database from below mentioned path:

```
xampp\mysql\data
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get database from xampp folder from following path

```
xampp\mysql\data
```

Answer (score 0):

Several others have suggested copying the datadir, but that isn't always a good idea (sometimes it works fine, but there are a number of cases where it can leave you with an incomplete or corrupt backup). If you're using a particular table type and (/or?) the MySQL server isn't running, it should be fine, but there are cases where it can cause problems.

My preferred method of backup up a database is the mysqldump command. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13427381/mysql-backup-database), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292446/backup-mysql-database), or [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-methods.html).

If you're having a specific problem with phpMyAdmin, you could ask about that with more detail.